# Using Grails with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails

Newbie having a hard time trying to set up mongodb with grails. I know I can't use the plugin install command because its been deprecated. Instead, I must add this to my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
compile ':mongodb:1.2.0' // or whatever is the latest vesrion
}
```

and then if don't have security set on mongodb do I still have to do this?

```
grails {
mongo {
    host = "localhost"
    port = 27017
    username = "blah"
    password = "blah"
    databaseName = "foo"
}
}
```

and that's it? No driver? Is the plugin the driver?

Answer (score 0):

with default MongoDB settings following should be enough

```
grails {
mongo {
    host = "localhost"
    port = 27017
    databaseName = "foo"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain. Assuming I make the connection to my db. How would I set something to a query in my controller? Something like foo.nameofCollection.find()? in order to get a result set?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is that you don't actually even need to have anything in your DataSource.groovy file. I completely made it blank and I am using the java MongoClient object to directly declare the host and port in the constructor of it. Not sure if its the best solution but it does work for me.